# Firestore offline cache

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an Android application which has to work offline for weeks, but can sync immediately with a remote DB as it goes online.

My question is can Firestore be a good option for this? How long does Firestore keep its offline cache?

Comment: It seems if you need to save huge data to offline cache, you need to sync data with `SQLite` or another local db or caching system.

Comment: Hi can you please tell how you are inserting data offline in firestore

Comment: How firestore behaves on writing data offline is really messy and unclear... the completion blocks are never returned....

Comment: Balazs, did you eventually use Firestore as an offline database that could last for weeks?
Just interested to hear if you went for something else?

Answer (score 17):

Firestore can be configured to persist data for such disconnected/offline usage. I recommend that you read the [enable offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) section in the docs, which contains this sample of enabling this feature:

> ```
> FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
> ```

```
        .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        .build();
db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

This persistence is actually enabled by default on Android and iOS, so the call above is not needed.

Your Android code that interact with the database will be the same whether you're connected or not, since the SDK simply works the same. If you want to detect whether data is coming from the cache (and thus potentially stale), read the section [Listen to offline data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#listen_to_offline_data) in the docs.

The data in the cache does not expire after a certain amount of time. The only two reasons data is removed from the cache:

1. The data has been removed from the server, in which case the client will remove it from the disk cache.
2. The client needs to purge its disk cache to make space for more recent data.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but my question was how long does Firestore keep its offline cache? I've read the link that you sent previously, it contained this: "This feature caches a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so your app can access the data when the device is offline." What does "actively using" means exactly? Will it delete my data if I don't access it after a day or a week? Can I configure it to keep all my data until I say not to?

Comment: There is no explicit cache expiration. It keeps the data until it needs to make space for newer data.

Comment: So if it decides it needs space, then it will delete my data? How much data can it store until it starts to delete my data? It is important to me because I need a reliable local database.

Comment: At this point there is no guarantee made when you enable persistence. It's a cache, not a guaranteed offline store. We're hoping to eventually add a kind of "pinning" to the API to allow you to get this guarantee, but for now you should expect that the cache is usable and useful but not guaranteed.

Comment: The code in the answer is redundent because the cache is enabled by default.

Comment: @GilGilbert and Frank, thank you both for the authoritative answer. I think this really needs to be in the documentation. It's kind of an essential piece of information!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT-25/5/2020: Francesco is correct, the docs link given in the comment does clarify that. It seems the cache size has been changed, by default it has been decreased to 40MB.

OLD: The following answer follows the official guide in the following link:

[Handling Cache size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_cache_size)

```
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
    .setCacheSizeBytes(FirebaseFirestoreSettings.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED)
    .build();
db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

The above code has a flag set for setCacheSize(), which will prevent your cache from 
being cleared. You can also specify the same in size. If you do not set this by default the size is 100MB.

As per the guide, there is a method to check if the data you query came from cache or the firestore. Also the moment your device is back online the firestore refreshes the cache, and keeps the data synchronized.

To answer your question, as you have to work with offline data for weeks, i suggest every time the data is fetched to store it in json/xml formats, as storing huge amount of data in cache is not a really good approach when thought of in terms of performance.

I hope i helped you clear some things out.

Comment: From the docs, it seems the default cache size is 40MB (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) instead of 100 MB.

Answer (score 2):

If you listen to data in Cloud Firestore, you will get immediate snapshots of cached data and also updates when your app is able to connect online:

```
final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
            return;
        }


        // Determine if the data came from the server or from cache
        String source = snapshot != null && snapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()
                ? "Local" : "Server";


        // Read the data
        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, source + " data: " + snapshot.getData());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, source + " data: null");
        }
    }
});
```

Persistence is enabled by default so this behavior does not require any configuration.