# How to persist the store values in react native?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

In my application,the home page fetches the Json response from my rest API.Then I add the products into the cart array.Initially,my store values are..

```
const DEFAULT_STATE_TRENDING = {
data:{},
specialoffdata:[],
banner:[],
offerstitle:[],
cart:[],
cartcount:0,
isFetching:false,
dataFetched:false,
error:false,
}
```

After i added the products the cart array and cart count becomes..

```
cart:[{...},{...}],
cartcount:cart.length
```

Now, i close my app.After reloading the app,the cart array becomes empty.How to persist the store values here?

Comment: Try using AsyncStorage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to persist the store values is by using this awesome library. [**Redux Persist**](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

It contains various `methods` and `levels` of `persistance`, with the ease of use.

`Installation` and `basic usage` is well documented on their [github docs](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use AsyncStorage

```
let response = await AsyncStorage.getItem('count'); //Read
AsyncStorage.setItem('count', this.state.count + '');
```

This way, you can access the 'count' in every component.

---

The most modern way is to use react's new context api, you define the context provider and consume it everywhere:

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light')

class ThemeProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {theme: 'light'}
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state.theme}> //<--- 'light' is exposed here
        {this.props.children}
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider>
        <ThemeContext.Consumer>
          {item => <div>{item}</div>} //<-- you consume the value ('light') here
        </ThemeContext.Consumer>
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

Either way, it is much lighter and easier than Redux or MobX.

Comment: Thank you..
Can you tell me how to get the current state values of my AsyncStorage..Like,for each action dispatching the state of the AsyncStorage gets changing.

Comment: let response = await AsyncStorage.getItem('count'); //Read

Comment: I used this line only.It produce internal error for me..Please have a look at my answer below i used to store the reducers state into AsyncStorage.Now i want to see the current values.

Comment: Do you know any library which attachable to new react context, and keep and update it for offline usage? e.g. reload a conversation history from the disk if there is.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi, try Firebase for react, see [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial)

Comment: @David Thanks for your answer and suggestion, but i need to store conversations offline, So i found ```realm```. I need to do more investigation. Thanks

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi firestore do support offline storage and auto sync! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771332/firestore-offline-cache

Comment: @David, yes fire store is a good solution. But i'm looking for independent open-source solution, So i found i can use ```realm``` as store and there is ```eventListener``` on realm objects, which will help too much. Thanks for your attention, Regards

Answer (score 0):

I used the AsyncStorage.In this way i persisted my store state values even after reloading,closing and opening app.

configureStore.js:

---

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import allReducers from './reducers';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const middleware = [ thunk,
                   ];

export default function configureStore() {
let store= createStore(
    allReducers,
    {},
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware),autoRehydrate())
    );
    console.log("Created store is"+store);debugger
    return store;
    }
```

App.js:

---

```
const store = configureStore();
export default class App extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
console.log("App.js started and its store value is"+store);debugger
SplashScreen.hide()
persistStore(
  store,
  {
    storage : AsyncStorage,
    whitelist : ['trending']
  }
);
}
render() {
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
  <MyStack/>
  </Provider>
);
}
}
```